# Flutter streaming radio doesn't restart after a call

Tags: flutter, background

I use audioplayers to listen to a radio channel (streaming) in Flutter. It works well in the background except when the user receives a call. In this case the playing stops but doesn't restart automatically at the end of the call.

```
AudioPlayer audioPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
const kUrl = "http://5.39.71.159:8865/stream";

Future play() async {
 int result = await audioPlayer.play(kUrl);

 setState(() {
   playerState = PlayerState.playing;
 });
}

Future stop() async {
 int result = await audioPlayer.stop();
}
```

How can I put my radio in pause mode when a call comes and restart the playing at the end of the call?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((AudioPlayerState s) => {
    print('Current player state: $s');
    setState(() => palyerState = s);
  });
```

Comment: Tried that, it doesn't fix the problem